# Is there a way to detect if object instance is deleted (in lambda)?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic-templates

I have this small template function to store my callback function for later "callback".

```
std::function<void(std::string)> stored_callback;

template<class ReadFileCallback, typename Object, class ...T>
void fileMgr_ReadWithCallback(std::string filename, ReadFileCallback callback, Object* object, T ...params) {
    std::cout << "fileMgr_ReadWithCallback is processing file: " << filename << std::endl;

    stored_callback= [=](std::string s) {
        (object->*callback)(s, params...);
    };
}

void calledLater() {
  stored_callback("somestring");
}
```

I'm using it from a class like this:

```
void MyClass::Read() {
  fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("myfile", &MyClass::ReadResult, this, fileId);
}
```

This works nicely, but I have a terrible fear that it can cause a real mess if `object` gets invalidated (goes out of scope).

As `MyClass` can be put onto heap:

```
MyClass* c=new MyClass();
c->Read(); // callback stored
delete c; // c invalidated
calledLater(); // ???
```

If I try running this, it does not cause any error. But if something overwrites `c`'s former space, it would cause a terrible UB. Or I'm mistaken?

Is there any way when `c` is deleted for either of these:

- **not** call the `stored_callback`, or
- **not** call `(object->*callback)(s, params...);`

Is this good for storing a weak_ptr?

```
stored_callback = [=](std::string s) { 
  std::weak_ptr<Object> obj = object; //or std::make_shared?
  if (auto spt = obj.lock()) (spt->*callback)(s, params...);
};
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)?

Comment: Store a [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to _prevent_ it being destroyed, or a [`weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to find out whether it was destroyed. Or just guarantee that it will not be destroyed by writing your program to be statically correct. You can't control or check the lifetime of a raw pointer though.

Comment: Given the above `stored_func` and lambda expression, how shall I modify it to store a weak pointer of `object`?

Comment: Allocate your object with `make_shared` and then use shared pointers throughout to manage its lifetime (or weak pointers when you want to track its lifetime without keeping it alive). This is pretty intrusive, because you're changing the ownership model entirely

Comment: `weak_ptr` only works for objects that are managed with `shared_ptr`. You can't take a "plain" object and expect `weak_ptr` to detect when it was destroyed. *Detecting whether an object has been destroyed is impossible, unless* you do it yourself somehow (like removing the callback in the object's destructor).

Comment: What if I store it on stack? It still can get out of scope, is weak_ptr still the way to check if it's valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect if object instance is deleted

Yes, so long as you manage its lifetime with [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), and optionally track it with [`weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) when you don't want to extend that lifetime.

There is no general way to do this for "unmanaged" objects, meaning those allocated and managed directly via raw pointers, or locals with automatic scope.

You can't detect whether the object still exists via a raw pointer, because if it was deleted or went out of scope, dereferencing the pointer is illegal in the first place. So, you must either

1. write your code to not destroy the object while the raw pointer exists (ie, static correctness)
2. not use raw pointers and instead use a smart pointer (most likely `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`) to control the object's lifetime
3. have the object somehow detach itself from callbacks when it is destroyed (which is intrusive, as now each object that could be used in a callback needs to know about it)